# intl: ^0.18.0 in flutter ask for data path in the argument

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

In  the updated version of intl package it is asked for two argument. One is locale and the other is data path both want in string form.

[image: In this picture you will see it]

Answer (score 0):

reference from the official documentation :

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
...
initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null);
```

Comment: it gives error in null and formatDates

Comment: can you show error

Comment: null).then(formatDates) red line below "null" and "formateDates"

Comment: try now updated answer.

Comment: still redline in below null